# Global Context - Check for undefined

Tags: javascript, function, typeof

Why does the following code result in three times `true`?

I was excepting `false` for the second step.

```
    function foo() {
        this.bar = function () { };
    };

    console.log("foo - defined : " + typeof window.foo !== 'undefined');
    console.log("bar - defined : " + typeof window.bar !== 'undefined');

    foo();

    console.log("bar - defined : " + typeof window.bar !== 'undefined');
```

Comment: You should be: `(typeof window.foo !== 'undefined')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` operator's precedence is higher than that of `!==`. Your expression means

```
("bar - defined : " + typeof window.bar) !== 'undefined' // always true (or an exception)
```

instead of

```
"bar - defined : " + (typeof window.bar !== 'undefined')
```

If you do the latter explicitly, you'll get the expected output:

```
foo - defined : true
bar - defined : false
bar - defined : true
```